# Can any power supply be made a current source with this circuit?

Tags: power-supply, current-source

The other day I built a basic buck power supply on a breadboard from scratch (i.e. sawtooth generator, comparator, zener power supplies for control circuitry and references, feedback loop, and low-pass filter for the power output).

It got me thinking - could any off-the-shelf power supply chip be made into a current source using the following arrangement of the feedback?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkKGIX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the sake of example here, this would be a buck converter with an internal 1V FB reference which has been designed as a 1A current source. Rather than the traditional voltage divider feedback loop for voltage feedback, this uses a 0.01\$ \Omega \$ feedback resistor with some generic amplifier block (could be an IA, could have an active low-pass filter as well for noise/anti-aliasing etc.) with a gain of 100x.

Once the voltage is increasingly ramped until the current through the resistor hits 1A, the feedback voltage will reach 1V - and so the power supply will maintain the voltage (and therefore current) at that level.

Obviously, buck, boost, or buck-boost would have to be chosen appropriately to ensure the output voltage was correctly reachable, over the desired current compliance range.

Any first-glance reasons why this wouldn't work?

Cheers.

EDIT: Decided to simulate it with a basic linear tech buck part. Seems to work (note, this has a reference of 2.21V). Obviously as some have pointed out, the op-amps will affect the transfer function in the feedback loop. I believe as long as the correct op-amps were chosen (high-frequency, high CMRR, proper filtering), this is a viable solution however. Feel free to disagree, but.

[image]

Comment: The devil is in the details. While the concept is fine, it is entirely possible that the closed feedback loop will be unstable. It depends on the frequency of the  current sense amp and the internals of the regulator.

Comment: The circuit as shown can't work since the +/- inputs of the opamp would switch the output at very low levels ..perhaps just a few uV. You need a way to detect both the output voltage and the output current.

Comment: @JackCreasey, since the gain is given on the schematic, we can assume the amplifier symbol doesn't indicate an op-amp.

Comment: If you want to demonstrate stability with a simulation, you should include a step change in the load as part of the simulation.

Comment: Or, to get a more explicit "proof" of stability, break the feedback loop and do an AC simulation to find the phase margin.

Comment: @ThePhoton Unfortunately a linear gain does not do it. You need a level detection function, so it certainly will not work as envisaged no matter what symbol you want to use.

Comment: All you did in the expanded circuit is to set a single voltage threshold and the regulator switches around that point. It isn't a constant current source.

Comment: @JackCreasey - What? The feedback voltage is proportional to current, as sensed by the 22.1 mohm resistor. With a gain of 100, this gives the required 2.21 volts operation at the FB pin for a current of one amp. It most certainly _is_ a constant current source.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I'm sorry, did you say this was a CC regulator. Try modulating the load resistance from 10 to 20 Ohms at 10-100 Hz and look at the output waveform. Does it look like a regulator? I don't deny the circuit uses a current threshold, but it's a very poor regulator.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast    What ...no feedback? One only has to look at the risetime of the current to realize that this is NOT a CC source. With 4+ mS risetime to 1A it's clear that it will not be able to provide constant current into a dynamic load. Providing a single switch point into a constant R load is not a valuable way to test a CC supplt either. But no-one seemed to notice.

Comment: @JackCreasey Depends on the application I guess. I'm designing this for driving TEC Modules - a response time in the millisecond range is acceptable :)

Comment: @DSWG Probably the one application this technique could be useful for. However consider the expense of your differential amplifier could be replaced by a simple single opamp with a sense resistor in the low side of the TEC module. That would be more convectional since you gain nothing by using the differential setup. In addition I wonder what sort of application you have that requires just a single voltage/current (really just a peak detector) setting for the TEC module. More typically this would be done using either a PWM  or variable CC regulator.

Comment: @JackCreasey the current threshold will be tuned by a digital pot present within the IA/DA/OA feedback area, for varying gain and therefore varying current output. As for why a differential amplifier, much like in a wheatstone bridge/thermistor application, they serve an advantage over a single op-amp by removing any common-mode noise with respect to ground (i.e. if there is 10mVp-p present in-line with the resistor from EMI or some other means, a differential amplifier tapping off both sides will cancel this out and give the resulting output with the noise removed).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with using a DC to DC converter as a 'power supply'.

The first one is stability, most DC to DC converters are only stable across a certain range of voltages.

The second one is dropout, most DC to DC converters drop out on the low end of the voltage range. The LT1076 is stable across this range, from the datasheet

> Buck Converter with Output Voltage Range of 2.5V to 50V

So conceivably you could use the current limiting function but after 2.5V it would drop out.

There is a schematic that I've seen from linear (that I can't find right now) If I remember right it uses the LT3042 (or simmilar LDO) to drop the remainder of the voltage down to get the full voltage output range.